# Is there any way to prevent users from deleting answers?

Tags: discussion

A while ago I wanted to refer to my old answer, but I've realised the question was most probably removed by an OP. That is not a first time I can see user posting a question and removing it from SE after receiving an answer. I believe this is highly unacceptable as the knowledge should be common for everyone. Not mentioning even effort of person answering to a given question (in my case I've spend over one hour).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[I'm not sure it's possible for a user to delete a question, once it's received a certain number of votes and answers.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25088/how-can-i-delete-my-post-on-stack-overflow)

See [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/131640):

> **When can't I delete my own post?**
>
> You can't delete answers that have been accepted.
>
> You can't delete any question that:
>
> - has an upvoted answer, or
> - has multiple answers (even if there are no upvotes)
>
> You can't delete any of your questions or answers if you haven't registered your account (that is, associated an OpenID with it).

Comment: I see, therefore he must have deleted it shortly after reading my answer. Thanks