# Migration Rationale Question

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Honestly, I'm not trying to be a pest, but I am a bit confused.  My previous question to Meta, [Deletion Rationale Clarification](https://dsp.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1563), seems to have concluded that the driving rationale behind the deletion policy was to preserve reputation points of the answerer over the effort they expended.

So far, so good.  The migration policy seems to be a stark constrast to this.

I answered a question in the DSP forum, [What is the moment when all oscillators aligned to make a jump called? [migrated]](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/47970), and my answer got an upvote and my reputation got a +10.  Then the question got migrated to the "English Language & Usage" forum.  Okay, since it was about finding the right word for something, that seems appropriate.

However, when it got migrated, I lost the +10.  Not that big of a deal, but it could have been larger.

The question remains in the question list with a [migrated] label at the end of the title.  When you click on it, you get redirected to the other forum.  That seems appropriate, too.

What I don't understand is why doesn't the question get the same treatment on the question list of my profile page.  That would seem to be the logical behavior for the system.  As it currently works, just like with the deleted case, I have no easy way of linking to that question.  Anyway, that's the way I think it should work so I am filing this under feature request.

Also, the question, with the [migrated] tag, disappears from the original forum after 30 days.  Why?

Here is a similar [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/302342) asking "why" it works this way and only getting a "how" answer.

Thanks,

Ced